# Data Access Layer without ORM

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I'm coding mmorpg server emulator (hobby project) and i've stopped on writing data access layer. The thing is that i can't use ORM (performance matter). I've read a lot about Repository pattern but it seems like it does not fit well into my project because I'm gonna need methods like: (player db) GetAllByLevel(...), GetByName(...), etc.
I want my application to be database agnostic. (I'm using sql server for now but i would like to add support for mysql later)
Which data access pattern would fit into my project?

Sorry for my bad english.

## Edit

One more question. I've read that repository pattern operates on the agreggate root.
I've got 3 tables player, player_friend and player_chest. Player is an agreggate root and if i'm not wrong i should create just one repository (PlayerRepository) that could have methods like: GetFriends([player id], ...), GetChest([player id], ...) and so on.
Am i right?

Comment: If done well, the overhead of ORM is negligible: your RDBMS is going to be the slowest part. Start with an ORM, and remove it later if you find that it drags your performance.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight has pointed out - it's usually a bad idea to over-optimise up-front.  Only discard the idea of using an ORM if you've run some performance tests and can prove it'll be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the help. Yet i will stay with plain sql (since i'm learning TSQL) and i've got most of the queries written already. To simplify things i use Dapper micro orm. :p

Comment: You are wrong. The ORM can be a significnat issue - most ORM's do a lot and that Comes with a hefty Price. I could advice the OP to look at BlToolkit which is a "shallow LINQ Provider" without the Performance costing igher operations and we used it successfully in ETL Scenarios issuing about a Million SQL Statements per second.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider removing your edit and creating another question in regards to the aggregate root problem. You should try to ask a single question on each post and be as specific as possible.

Comment: Wow. Archaeologist :D The question is from last year. ; p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read a lot about Repository pattern but it seems like it does not fit well into my project because I'm gonna need methods like: (player db) GetAllByLevel(...), GetByName(...), etc.

On the contrary. There are a lot of faulty repository pattern examples out (typically leaky abstractions) which teach you wrong. `GetAllByLevel` is imho a good method since it describes the role of the method quite clear.

I've written about the repository pattern: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/. Do also read the abstraction link in the beginning of the article.

> The thing is that i can't use ORM (performance matter).

No problem. The repository pattern is used to abstract away the data source, no matter which kind it is.

If you want to use vanilla ADO.NET you can read this blog post: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/

> One more question. I've read that repository pattern operates on the agreggate root. I've got 3 tables player, player_friend and player_chest. Player is an agreggate root and if i'm not wrong i should create just one repository (PlayerRepository) that could have methods like: GetFriends([player id], ...), GetChest([player id], ...) and so on. Am i right?

No. I would say that Friends is a root too. Read this article about designing aggregates: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check out the links you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Repository is the way to go. The point is that you can have multiple implementations of the same repository interface, one for sql server another one for oracle or postgresql. You don't necessarily have one generic implementation that supports all possible databases (this would be quite difficult).

The concrete implementation can use any specific features of the concrete dbms to fit your performance criteria.

Comment: Yeah i know that. The thing is that i've read that repository pattern should not contain methods like ex: GetAllByLevel, GetByName, etc.

Comment: And? You don't need an orm to implement these methods. Repository can be implemented with or without an orm.